# Edit text loses focus after errasing the value and interacting with a listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-edittext

My program has a edittext field that needs to be focused at all times but ,for some reason ,after it detectes the data is duplicated and deletes it, it should refocus but it dosent.

This code below checks if the code is duplicated on the last 5 codes scanned. if it is not duplicated it adds it to the 5 last codes added and it sends it to a database (no problem here, that part works great), if it's duplicated then it clears the field and it attemps to refocus on the edit text, but here is where the code fails.

Notes:

`txtmanualbarcode` is an edit Text.

`setInputType(inputType.Type_NULL)` hides the keyboard as it is not needed.

`scanneditems` is an array list of the last 5 codes.

`allscanneditems` is the complete list of codes.

If further code or explanation is needed please ask me, this error has been dragging me down for some days.

```java
    public void addScannedItem(final QrScannedItem it) {
        boolean duplicado = false;
        for (int a = 0; a < scannedItems.size(); a++) {
            if (scannedItems.get(a).qr_code.compareTo(it.qr_code) == 0) {
                txtmanualbarcode.setText("");
                txtmanualbarcode.clearFocus();
                txtmanualbarcode.requestFocus();
                txtmanualbarcode.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                duplicado = true;

            }
        }


        if (!duplicado) {
            scannedItems.add(0, it);
            if (scannedItems.size() > 5) {
                scannedItems.remove(5);
                allScannedItems.add(0, it);

            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            showProgressBar();
            Thread thr = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        String state = status.compareTo("in") == 0 ? "1" : "0";
                        String time = getScanTime();
                        JSONObject obj = QrCourseServer.checkin(state, it.qr_code, time, course.id, AppCache.currentUser.token);
                        String msg = obj.getString("message");
                        it.extraMessage = msg;
                        if (msg.toLowerCase().compareTo("socio") == 0) {
                            //play socio beep
                            playMp3Resource(R.raw.ding);
                        } else {
                            //play no socio beep
                            playMp3Resource(R.raw.dingdong);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                        it.extraMessage = ex.getMessage();
                        playMp3Resource(R.raw.error);
                        //UIHelper.msbox("Error",ex.getMessage(),ScanActivity.this);
                    } finally {
                        closeProgressBar();
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                txtmanualbarcode.setText("");
                                txtmanualbarcode.requestFocus();
                                txtmanualbarcode.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);


                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
            thr.start();
        } else {
            txtmanualbarcode.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

My problem resides (probably) within the first `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be to use `InputMethodManager` to make it hide the keyboard without your input losing focus.

Using helper class defined below you can update your code and get rid of using `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)`. Also, do not clear focus before requesting focus again. There is no use and potentially it can be the source of bugs.

```
    for (int a = 0; a < scannedItems.size(); a++) {
        if (scannedItems.get(a).qr_code.compareTo(it.qr_code) == 0) {
            txtmanualbarcode.setText("");
            txtmanualbarcode.requestFocus();
            KeyboardHelper.hideKeyboard(txtmanualbarcode);
            duplicado = true;

        }
    }
```

Code to hide keyboard without losing focus:

```
public class KeyboardHelper {

    public static void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        if (view.getContext() == null) {
            Log.d(KeyboardHelper.class.getSimpleName(), "hideKeyboard failed. View detached");
            return;
        }

        InputMethodManager mgr = getInputManagerFromContext(view.getContext());

        if (mgr != null) {
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    private static InputMethodManager getInputManagerFromContext(Context context) {
        return (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and removed all setinputtype calls, but my issue persists, i will continue invetigating.